# Some system encode vietnamese combining accent as individual utf-8 characters

Tags: dart, unicode, encode

I have a Vietnamese string and I want to put this string to POST query param. But with same string on different devices, I received different utf-8 characters. 
Eg: "làm" => [108, 97, 204, 128, 109]  or  [108, 195, 160, 109]
This issue because some system encode vietnamese combining accent as individual utf-8 characters 
(In abobe example: '`' => 'à')
So how can i convert the first encode to the second?. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply [Unicode Normalization](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/). For the version you're describing, you'll likely want NFC, which maintains canonical equivalence, and composes everything that can be composed.

If you search for "dart unicode normalization" you should find some libraries that do this.

Comment: Oh yeah! That is exactly what i want. Thank you for your great answer